# Energy levels database

Tags: energy, orbitals, reference-request

Does anybody know where to find a database for atomic and molecular energy levels, with the corresponding energy values for each level? It would be needed just for small molecules. I tried the [NIST website](http://cccbdb.nist.gov/introx.asp) but it only has the ground state energies.

Comment: It does not get you all orbitals, but the [Pitt Quantum Repository](https://pqr.pitt.edu/) contains at least calculated HOMO and LUMO values for over 100,000 molecules.

Comment: Hi Ben, I could not find the energy levels on that website.

Comment: Go to the site and search for a compound, like [formaldehyde](https://pqr.pitt.edu/mol/WSFSSNUMVMOOMR-UHFFFAOYSA-N). Then, in the properties pane on the left, click the link to "Detailed". HOMO and LUMO energies will show up in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Pitt Quantum Repository](https://pqr.pitt.edu/) can get you what you want, at least for molecular species.

1. Go to the PQR at http://pqr.pitt.edu.
2. Search for a molecule, like [benzaldehyde](https://pqr.pitt.edu/mol/HUMNYLRZRPPJDN-UHFFFAOYSA-N).
3. Click "Detailed" on the properties pane.
4. You can see HOMO and LUMO in the list.
5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on the link to "Get JSON data".
6. The JSON file will open in your browser or you will download. You should be able to open it with a text editor. There will be a list of orbital energies for the set of molecular orbitals computed from the valence atomic orbitals. For example, for [benzaldhyde](https://pqr.pitt.edu/api/json/HUMNYLRZRPPJDN-UHFFFAOYSA-N).

   ```
   "homo": -10.168, 
   "lumo": -0.712, 
   "orbitals": [
   "-31.27648", 
   "-30.67710", 
   "-26.81219", 
   "-26.23865", 
   "-23.01445", 
   "-21.46816", 
   "-20.14594", 
   "-18.05465", 
   "-16.39792", 
   "-15.70143", 
   "-14.95762", 
   "-14.67105", 
   "-14.63486", 
   "-14.38581", 
   "-13.35746", 
   "-12.66484", 
   "-12.26937", 
   "-10.28746", 
   "-10.23037", 
   "-10.16786", 
   "-0.71215", 
   "-0.10196", 
   "1.01720", 
   "2.30473", 
   "3.35595", 
   "3.89337", 
   "4.34241", 
   "4.54954", 
   "4.71066", 
   "4.82113", 
   "4.99402", 
   "5.26380", 
   "5.29598", 
   "5.54486", 
   "5.70599", 
   "5.83103", 
   "5.89240", 
   "6.03437"
   ],
   ```

Comment: Though it seems that the database doesn't have all the molecules. For example I cannot find simple molecules as LiH or BeH.

Comment: They are there. You need to search by their compound name: [Lithium hydride](https://pqr.pitt.edu/mol/SIAPCJWMELPYOE-UHFFFAOYSA-N), [beryllium hydride](https://pqr.pitt.edu/mol/RWASOQSEFLDYLC-UHFFFAOYSA-N)